Stripe payment not going through in production but working in development
I have a django project that I am deploying and have a stripe integration for payments in it. It works perfectly fine locally and goes through but does not work on my linux server. What could be causing this and how can I make the payment work on my deployed version?
Lead:
The only hit of issue I am getting is that my gunicorn logs show that the /charge/ endpoint that I am using to charge is forbidden, but I'm not sure what is really causing this as this is so bizarre.
Thank you so much!
Context:
I have https, and the code doesnt detect any errors (redirects to success page and stripe doesnt give errors). I just allowed all of the stripe IP's through my firewalls using sudo ufw (the api.stripe.com ones: https://docs.stripe.com/ips).  The code is the exact same, the api keys are the same

What is the exact error message or exceptions you're facing? Is the error from Stripe API or your own server?
